# The pictures below are moving when hovering

Tags: html, css

I started learning web programming and i want to test some features but there is a problem, when I bring the mouse on the above photos, the bottom ones change place like in the photo. The photos below are on the left in the first opening, while hovering on the top one, it shifts to the right. 
Like this:

[image: like this]

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#gallery{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.item-container{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

.gallery-item{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    transition: border 0.4s linear;

}

.gallery-item:hover{
    border: 3px solid #777;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-item img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: contain;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;

}

.description{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Art Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   
   <div id="gallery">
     <div class="item-container">
      
      <div class="gallery-item">
         
          <a href="img/1.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" >
          </a>
          
          <div class="description">
              description about image gallery item
          </div>
          
          
      </div>
    </div>
         </div>
    
    <div id="gallery">
     <div class="item-container">
      
      <div class="gallery-item">
         
          <a href="img/2.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" >
          </a>
          
          <div class="description">
              description about image gallery item
          </div>
          
          
      </div>
    </div>
         </div>
    
    <div id="gallery">
     <div class="item-container">
      
      <div class="gallery-item">
         
          <a href="img/3.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="" >
          </a>
          
          <div class="description">
              description about image gallery item
          </div>
          
          
      </div>
    </div>
         </div>
    
    <div id="gallery">
     <div class="item-container">
      
      <div class="gallery-item">
         
          <a href="img/4.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="" >
          </a>
          
          <div class="description">
              description about image gallery item
          </div>
          
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
<div id="gallery">
     <div class="item-container">
      
      <div class="gallery-item">
         
          <a href="img/5.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="" >
          </a>
          
          <div class="description">
              description about image gallery item
          </div>
          
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
    <div id="gallery">
     <div class="item-container">
      
      <div class="gallery-item">
         
          <a href="img/6.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="" >
          </a>
          
          <div class="description">
              description about image gallery item
          </div>
          
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
             
   

</body>
</html>
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: You are increasing the size of the border, but keeping the same total size, so the image has to shrink. What would you expect/want to happen in this situation?

Comment: when you hover an image it is taking some extra space and thus the images will move if they don't fit in the space assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer

Add outline instant of border

The problem with your border hover css

From

```
.gallery-item:hover{
    border: 3px solid #777; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

To

```
.gallery-item:hover{
    border: 1px solid #777; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#gallery{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.item-container{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

.gallery-item{
    outline: 1px solid #ccc;
    transition: border 0.4s linear;

}

.gallery-item:hover{
    outline: 3px solid #777; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-item img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: contain;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;

}

.description{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Art Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   
   <div id="gallery">
     <div class="item-container">
      
      <div class="gallery-item">
         
          <a href="img/1.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" >
          </a>
          
          <div class="description">
              description about image gallery item
          </div>
          
          
      </div>
    </div>
         </div>
    
    <div id="gallery">
     <div class="item-container">
      
      <div class="gallery-item">
         
          <a href="img/2.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" >
          </a>
          
          <div class="description">
              description about image gallery item
          </div>
          
          
      </div>
    </div>
         </div>
    
    <div id="gallery">
     <div class="item-container">
      
      <div class="gallery-item">
         
          <a href="img/3.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="" >
          </a>
          
          <div class="description">
              description about image gallery item
          </div>
          
          
      </div>
    </div>
         </div>
    
    <div id="gallery">
     <div class="item-container">
      
      <div class="gallery-item">
         
          <a href="img/4.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="" >
          </a>
          
          <div class="description">
              description about image gallery item
          </div>
          
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
<div id="gallery">
     <div class="item-container">
      
      <div class="gallery-item">
         
          <a href="img/5.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="" >
          </a>
          
          <div class="description">
              description about image gallery item
          </div>
          
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
    <div id="gallery">
     <div class="item-container">
      
      <div class="gallery-item">
         
          <a href="img/6.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="" >
          </a>
          
          <div class="description">
              description about image gallery item
          </div>
          
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is correct. but what if the OP wants that border and the images not to move?